# Add reference using GUID

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to activate Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility Library(version 5.3) programmatically using GUID. My code encounters the error "Object library not registered" when trying to do this. I have enabled access to VBProjects.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub ActivateReferenceLibrary()


    'Activate Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility Library (version 5.3)
      ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 0, 0



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
Major:=5, Minor:=3
```

You may want to see [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264769(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! This works ! However, after the code has executed, I get the dialogue box: "Can't enter break mode at this time". Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Nevermind! SIlly me, I was running the code using F8.. works when it executes normally